# android - how to handle the bottom toolbar on amazon kindle fire

Tags: android, toolbar, tablet, kindle-fire

it seems that on amazon kindle there is a bottom toolbar that takes space of my full screen app , yet the app itself thinks that it got the entire screen , so a part of it is always hidden by the toolbar.

the situation is different on other tablets , so i guess the problem is with amazon kindle fire.

is there a way to overcome this issue?

maybe there is an sdk for amazon kindle fire which can help with it? maybe a way to put the toolbar on the upper side , or make the app take the real size that it can, excluding the space taken by the toolbar?

please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe there is an sdk for amazon kindle fire which can help with it?

Not at this time.

> maybe a way to put the toolbar on the upper side

No, sorry.

> make the app take the real size that it can, excluding the space taken by the toolbar?

You are welcome to write the code for that. As [the Kindle Fire documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire) states:

> *Note: The device will reserve 20px to display a soft key menu, making the effective portrait resolution 1004px high x 600px wide and the effective landscape resolution 580px high x 1024px wide.

So, for the Fire, make sure you are not using any more space than the above dimensions, and you will not have to worry about the bar.

Comment: so , no way to handle this problem , other than identify that the device is kindle fire , and then reserve some empty space (of height 20px ? or is it 20dp?) at the bottom for the toolbar?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: All I can tell you is what Amazon tells you, and Amazon has not documented any other approach. Of course, you could design your UI to take the full screen but just not have anything important in those bottom 20px.

Comment: i understand . i hope that i won't have any problems with future amazon devices if i assume this 20px space is taken . thank you for your time .

Comment: Some applications seem to not show the search icon on every activity.  is there some control over this?

Comment: http:/www.sackoverflow.com/questions/10956808/kindle-fire-menu-actionbar-search-icon-shows-on-every-activity-need-to-supres

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a way to get the SIDE menu width, you can try the code below which worked for me:

```
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    int screen_width = size.x;

    int kindleSideMenuWidth = (int) (screen_width * 0.06171875);
```

0.06171875 is the ratio, which i`v calculated with the good old "Paint".
Hopes it helps.

Comment: do you think this is what they (amazon) use?